# Xamarin and Travis-ci

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, mono, travis-ci

I have a simple hello world app that fails to build. I'm getting the following output from the build.

```
Warnings:
/home/travis/build/chaione/csharptrav/csharp/csharp.iOS/csharp.iOS.csproj:  warning : Could not find project file /usr/lib/mono/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.CSharp.targets, to import. Ignoring.
/home/travis/build/chaione/csharptrav/csharp/csharp.Droid/csharp.Droid.csproj:  warning : Could not find project file /usr/lib/mono/xbuild/Novell/Novell.MonoDroid.CSharp.targets, to import. Ignoring.

Errors: 
/home/travis/build/chaione/csharptrav/csharp/csharp.sln (default targets) ->
(Build target) ->
    /home/travis/build/chaione/csharptrav/csharp/csharp.iOS/csharp.iOS.csproj: error : /home/travis/build/chaione/csharptrav/csharp/csharp.iOS/csharp.iOS.csproj: /home/travis/build/chaione/csharptrav/csharp/csharp.iOS/csharp.iOS.csproj could not import "$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.CSharp.targets"
```

What do I need to do get this to build? The solution consist of 6 projects: Core PCL(profile 78), Android, iOS, Android UI test, iOS UI test, UnitTest (using NUnit).

Comment: Do you have a Xamarin License configured in the Travis host ?

Comment: Did you manage to figure out the solution? If yes, then please post the solution. I ma facing similar issue. No much documentation available on this.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue like that and moved to https://www.appveyor.com/. Here https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/appveyor.yml you can find a link to appveyor.yml which plays the role as .travis.yml. Please note that you have to have a Xamain license. The credentials are secured in the appveyor.yml file.